# Simple game in C using getch - segfault problem?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

The following code has segfault problems (It is also posted [at pastebin](http://pastebin.ca/1982473)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "mygetch.h"

#define MAX_SIZE 255
#define SCR_CLEAR "\033[2J\033[;H"

void getgrid(int, int);
void resetgrid(void);
void getkey(void);


static bool grid[5][5] = {{0,0,0,0,0},
                           {0,0,0,0,0},
                           {0,0,0,0,0},
                           {0,0,0,0,0},
                           {0,0,0,0,0}};


int main() {

    while(1) {
        getkey();
    }


    return 0;
}

void getgrid(int xpos, int ypos) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    grid[xpos][ypos] = 1;

    for(x = 0; x <= 4; x++) {
        for(y = 0; y <= 4; y++) {
            printf("%i ", grid[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


void resetgrid() {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for(x = 0; x <= 4; x++) {
        for(y = 0; y <= 4; y++) {
            grid[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void getkey() {
    static int xpos = 0;
    static int ypos = 0;
    int c = mygetch();

    //0x41 = up.. apparently on my linux console?
    //0x42 = down
    //0x44 = left
    //0x43 = right

    if(c == 0x41 && ypos != 0) {
        ypos--;
    } else if(c == 0x42 && ypos != 4) {
        ypos++;
    } else if(c == 0x44 && xpos != 4) {
        xpos--;
    } else if(c == 0x43 && xpos != 0) {
        xpos++;
    }

    resetgrid();
    printf(SCR_CLEAR);
    getgrid(xpos, ypos);
}
```

You can assume `mygetch()` returns an ASCII integer code point, on my linux console up down left and right are A/B/C/D, so I mapped them as so.

My problem is for some reason, even though I defined the multidimensional array correctly, when I press up/down/left/right left and right do not work, they go off screen and cause a segfault, now I know the keys are mapped correctly, so I do not know why `y--` `y++` etc. will not correctly function unless I made an error in defining the array or somewhere else.

I will  definitely learn a lot from fixing this and doing more, but it is just a thing for fun I am wishing to do.

Comment: I moved the pastebin content into the post. IMHO, it is preferred to keep questions at SO self-contained where possible so that they remain relevant even when external sites get updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your boundary conditions are inverted for *left* and *right*. You should have:

```
if (c == 0x41 && ypos != 0) {
    ypos--;
} else if(c == 0x42 && ypos != 4) {
    ypos++;
} else if(c == 0x44 && xpos != 0) {
    xpos--;
} else if(c == 0x43 && xpos != 4) {
    xpos++;
}
```

Instead of:

```
if (c == 0x41 && ypos != 0) {
    ypos--;
} else if(c == 0x42 && ypos != 4) {
    ypos++;
} else if(c == 0x44 && xpos != 4) {
    xpos--;
} else if(c == 0x43 && xpos != 0) {
    xpos++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. For some odd reason the axes are inversed, but that is much simpler to fix, I am now getting into the "fun" part of the game!